# How to stop a live stream video being downloaded through youtube-dl?

Tags: python, download, live-streaming, youtube-dl

I am downloading a wav format audio through youtube-dl and it is downloading. Currently I stop the code by Ctrl + C but I want to stop it through python code

My code for the program is following. I have created a function named download(). From main I create a thread and start it. I wait 30 seconds for the thread to finish its work but the thread doesn't end, it keeps on running so that's why I use Ctrl + C to end the code.

```
import youtube_dl
from multiprocessing import Process
from threading import Timer
import time
import threading

    
#set options for the download
def download():
    options = {
        'nopart': True,
        'format': 'bestaudio/best',
        'outtmpl': '%(title)s.%(ext)s',
        'postprocessors': [{
            'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
            'preferredcodec': 'wav',
            'preferredquality': '192',
            'start'
        }],
        
    }

    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(options) as ydl:
        ydl.download(['https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q130lTDaua0'])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    e = threading.Event()
    t = threading.Thread(target=download, args=())
    t.start()

    # wait 30 seconds for the thread to finish its work
    t.join(30)
    if t.is_alive():
        print ("thread is not done, setting event to kill thread.")
        e.set()
    else:
        print ("thread has already finished.")
```

Comment: Seems similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66236507/stoping-a-stream-from-downloading-in-youtube-dl)

Comment: This doesn't work [link] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66236507/stoping-a-stream-from-downloading-in-youtube-dl

Comment: What doesn't work?  Running in a separate process certainly works -- you can terminate that other process at any time.  The downloader does have a way to do progress callbacks, but it doesn't let you cancel things.

Comment: The process is not killed. I have tried it, it keeps on downloading.

Comment: what about using p.kill?